# Windows 7 Search Parameters For Searching File Contents

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

Is it possible to search the contents of files from the Windows 8/7 explorer search? Without the search timing out? There are no parameters when you click "file contents" at "Search again in" at the bottom of the results.

There are other clickable parameters that show when you start typing, such as datemodified: and size:(large, small, huge, etc...).

Bring back the Windows 2000 search box (still available on XP via registry hack :-))

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change your search parameters.A possible solution to search the content of files is presented [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/in-windows-7-i-want-to-search-for-all-files/aadfe1f1-4a33-406b-8e72-bb920efa4f30?auth=1).

An alternative solution might be Lookeen [Desktop Search](https://lookeen.com/solutions/desktop-search/desktop-search.html). It also searches the content of files and uses real-time indexing for fast search results.

Comment: My employer is the developer of this tool.